# Laravel DB insert error 500

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, post, insert

Unable to insert into database in a Laravel controller. Below is the controller. 
I keep getting an error highlight in Dreamweaver at the following line:

```
$users = DB::table('records')->insert([
    'product' => 'john@example.com',
    'name' => 'john@example.com',
    'email' => 'john@example.com'
]);
```

> I keep getting error 500

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class create extends Controller
{
    //
    public function createRecord(Request $request){
        json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        //return $request;
        //$something ='asdf';
        //return $something;

        $users = DB::table('records')->insert([
            'product' => 'john@example.com',
            'name' => 'john@example.com',
            'email' => 'john@example.com'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the screenshot of the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see anything wrong with this. Have you ensured that the data type matches in the database to what you are inserting? It's hard to really gather this when you haven't provided the 500 error you are receiving.

Try the following instead:

1. Create your model. `php artisan make:model Record`
2. Instantiate a new instance of that model. `$record = new \App\Record;`
3. Add your data using the Eloquent ORM.

   ```
   $record->product = "john@example.com";
   $record->name = "john@example.com";
   $record->email = "john@example.com";
   ```
4. Finally, save it: `$record->save();`

So, in full this would look like the following:

```
 $record = new \App\Record;
 $record->product = "john@example.com";
 $record->name = "john@example.com";
 $record->email = "john@example.com";
 $record->save();
```

See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data=array(

              'product' => 'john@example.com',
              'name' => 'john@example.com',
              'email' => 'john@example.com',
           );

$users = DB::table('records')->insert($data);
```